# Magento2 how do I add a new navigation into the acount navigation

Tags: magento2, navigation, myaccount, account

In magento2 path

`wowshop/app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/wowshop/GShop_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`

I have a code of this

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main.account_nav">
            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation"><!--ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"-->
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-logout-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/logout</argument>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Logout</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    
                </referenceBlock>
                <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
                 <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/order/history</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order History</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
                <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-newpassword-change-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wishlist</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </referenceBlock>
                <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" >
                    <arguments>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/preorder/history</argument>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pre Order History</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </referenceBlock>
               <!--  <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-track-my-order-link" after="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" >
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">order-tracking</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Track My Order</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block> -->
                 <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-my-voucher-link" >
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/customer/voucher</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Vouchers</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-my-rewards-link" after="customer-account-navigation-track-my-order-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/customer/wowcashback</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">WOW Rewards</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
            <!-- <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="recent_orders" template="Magento_Sales::reorder/sidebar.phtml"/> -->
            
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Reorder\Sidebar" name="recent_orders" template="Magento_Sales::reorder/sidebar.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-voucher-link" remove="false"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-perks" remove="true"/>
        
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.giftcardaccount" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-saved-cards-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

which produce this account navigation view

[image]

I am so confused as to how the view appear like this

I wanted to make a view that appear like this

1. Account Information
2. Order History
3. Pre Order History
4. My Wishlist
5. My Vouchers
6. WOW Rewards
7. Logout

I don't know how do the My Invitations appear even though I didnt put any of that in code, I am able to hide it, but the big problem I am facing is the missing Wow Rewards menu which I really need, whenever I try to adjust something another problem appear, I figure I might be missing some understanding here

Really appreciate if anyone can provide a direct solution and explanation on how to change this part of the code

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="tutorial_custom_my_account">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tutorial/account/custom</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My custom</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</argument>
                    <argument name="navigation" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

**Or Create a file : app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="tutorial_custom_my_account">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">tutorial/account/custom</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My custom</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</argument>
                    <argument name="navigation" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-magento-invitation-link" remove="true"/>
```

and in module xml add `Magento_Invitation` as module dependency

Replace you customer_account.xml file with this

```
    <!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
      label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current"
               name="customer-account-navigation-logout-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/logout</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Logout</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface"
               name="customer-account-navigation-newpassword-change-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">wishlist</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Wishlist</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface"
               name="customer-account-navigation-my-voucher-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/customer/voucher</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Vouchers</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface"
               name="customer-account-navigation-my-rewards-link"
               after="customer-account-navigation-track-my-order-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/customer/wowcashback</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">WOW Rewards</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/order/history</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order History</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/preorder/history</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pre Order History</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>


    <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Reorder\Sidebar" name="recent_orders"
               template="Magento_Sales::reorder/sidebar.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-voucher-link" remove="false"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-perks" remove="true"/>

    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.giftcardaccount" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-saved-cards-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
    <!-- My Invitations -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-magento-invitation-link" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

[image]